# How to fetch meta descripion of product in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product

I want to fetch product's meta description.how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$product->getMetaDescription()` for fetching the product meta description of product

and `$product->getShortDescription();` for fetching short description

and  `$product->getDescription();`  to fetch product description.